# 550 Executable files are not allowed in compressed files

Tags: php, email, smtp, zip

Due to user's requirement, I have to send automated emails with .zip file attachments to a number of clients. 
It was working properly until a few days ago.
All outgoing emails with .zip file attachments which are automatically sent by PHP script are not delivered to recipients.
And I got the returning email with the error "SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:550 Executable files are not allowed in compressed files.".

Here's is the part of the returning email ;

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> my-address@gmail.com
>   host 2374.smtp.antispamcloud.com [94.75.244.183]
>   SMTP error from remote mail server after end of
>   data:   550 Executable files are not allowed in compressed files.
>
> ------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
>
> Return-path:  Received: from user by cx1.oryon.net
>   with local (Exim 4.85_1)    (envelope-from )    id
>   1aqAZt-000008-QZ; Wed, 13 Apr 2016 10:30:50 +0800 To:
>   my-address@gmail.com Subject: Email-subject MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
>   boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x4f4b65625e5ee2220745d0c732d81cb2x"
>   From: Sender  Reply-To: sender@my-domain.com
>   Message-Id:  Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016
>   10:30:49 +0800 X-oryonnetworks-MailScanner-Information: Please contact
>   the ISP for more information X-oryonnetworks-MailScanner-ID:
>   1aqAZt-000008-QZ X-oryonnetworks-MailScanner: Not scanned: please
>   contact your Internet E-Mail Service Provider for details
>   X-oryonnetworks-MailScanner-SpamCheck:
>   X-oryonnetworks-MailScanner-From: user@cx1.oryon.net X-Spam-Status: No
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>
> --==Multipart_Boundary_x4f4b65625e5ee2220745d0c732d81cb2x Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   7bit

Please help me fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the mail header, the recipient is a gmail id and the bounce message indicates that the mail was rejected by the recipient server. As a security policy gmail blocks attachments containing executables, even though they are compressed. You may refer their KB Some file types are blocked - Gmail Help for further reference.